# TypeError: string indices must be integers on JSON from a cURL command

Tags: python, bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to retrieve a specific data from an API using cURL command.

```js
{  
   "server":{  
      "volumes":{  
         "0":{  
            "id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have this cURL command piped to a Python script:

```sh
ID_VOLUME=$(curl -s https://URL/API -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json, re; print [i['volumes']['0']['id'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['server']]")
echo "$ID_VOLUME"
```

For clarity, the `-c` switch runs

```python
import sys, json, re
print [i['volumes']['0']['id'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['server']]
```

The error I get:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I expect to get the id.

Comment: Consider using `requests` or some other Python module instead of `curl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over a *dictionary*, so in your `for` loop:

```
[i['volumes']['0']['id'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['server']]
```

`i` is a key in the `server` dictionary, which is a string. Since the `'server'` dictionary only has a single key, that would be `'volumes'`.

You don't even need a loop, just access the nested value directly:

```
json.load(sys.stdin)['server']['volumes']['0']['id']
```

If you wanted to iterate over multiple volumes, then iterate over the *values* of the `result['server']['volumes']` dictionary:

```
[vol['id'] for vol in json.load(sys.stdin)['server']['volumes'].values()]
```

You may want to look at the [`jq` command-line tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead to extract JSON data in a pipe:

```sh
... | jq -r '.server.volumes."0".id'
```

or if you want all ids, not just the one for `"0"`:

```sh
... | jq -r '.server.volumes[] | .id'
```

The `-r` switch tells `jq` to output the id as a raw string rather than a JSON-encoded string.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```sh
$ jq ".server.volumes.\"0\".id" so.json
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```